# Does BouncyCastle-PCL support Xades and Cades?

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, bouncycastle

I am looking for Xades and Pades library (ies) in .NET Core.

Does BouncyCastle-PCL support Xades and Cades ?

- If yes Does anyone sample(s) for it ?
- If No what is your solution for using/having Xades and Cades in .NET Core ?

Comment: Bouncycastle-java does not implement these formats. I guess neither in .NET.

Comment: I hope @oren-novotny help us for clarification